# Prevent jQuery code from executing multiple times

Tags: html, jquery

When I click on reply button 1 and reply button 2 alternatively, then the second time I click on reply button 2, the code fires multiple times. Kindly assist me to stop the code from firing multiple times. I have gone through similar questions on SO but I have not yet had solution.

**Edit:** I want the `post_reply` function to be called only after the first `ajax` call has been successful and that the `#reply-btn-2` button has been clicked

**Edit 2:** My original code works like this:

(1) When reply button 1 is clicked, call first ajax;

(2) When the first ajax is successful, create new HTML button called reply button 2

(3) When the reply button 2 is pressed, react according to the click.

This explains the reason why the `post_reply` function is called inside the first ajax.

```js
function post_reply(){
    
    $('#reply-btn-2').click(function(e){
        
        var text2 = 'Reply 2<br>';
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit':1, 'post':2}
            
        }).done(function(response){
            $('.place-replies-here').append(text2);
            
            
        });
    });
    
}
$('#reply-btn-1').click(function(e){
    
    var text1 = 'Reply 1<br>';
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit':1, 'post':2}
        
    }).done(function(response){
        $('.place-replies-here').append(text1);
        
        
        post_reply();
    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "place-replies-here"></div>

<div id = "reply-btn-1" style = "height:40px; width:100px;background:green;color:#fff; padding:5px; margin:8px;" class = "reply-btn">
    Reply 1
</div> 

<div id = "reply-btn-2"  style = "height:40px; width:100px;background:green;color:#fff;padding:5px; margin:8px;" class = "btn btn-success reply-btn">
    Reply 2
</div>
```

Comment: You did wrap your click EventListener for reply 1 in the function `post_reply()` which is not executed directly but only if the ajax request that gets only executed when clicking reply 1 was successful. Are you sure you want to define this click event when the function is called or immediately? Then you should outsource it into global scope.

Comment: Why are you binding events multiple times? Every time you call `post_reply` you add another click event to the element. So either you remove the events or you say "hey i added it, do not do it again" with some sort of boolean check.

Comment: I have edited my question. It is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Your code had some logic flaws. You added a click event listener to the Reply1 button that when will be fired will add a click event listener to the Reply2. It didn't make sense. Every single time you clicked the button Reply1 it was going to add an extra listener again to the same Reply2 button again and again. So that when the click event will fire for Reply2, it will run all the listeners added to the event.

In this demo I made sure you add the click event listener once only to both the button elements.

Actually the second button doesn't exist at first defined in the html. It gets created when the first button gets pressed the first time. From that moment on if the first button will be clicked again, it won't create infinite buttons again and again.

**Plus I used the Promise method `always` instead of `done` because otherwise the code wouldn't run at all here.**

```js
function createAndAppendSecondButton(){
  //create the element for the second button
  const secondButton =
    $("<button></button>")
      .prop('id','reply-btn-2')
      .addClass('reply-btn btn btn-success')
      .text('Reply 2');           
  
  //attach an click event listener to the element
  secondButton.click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'submit':1, 'post':2}            
    })
    //to be replaced with .done(function(response){
    .always(function(response){    
      const text2 = 'Reply 2<br>';        
      $('.place-replies-here').append(text2);                        
    });
  });
  
  //append the element to the dom
  $('#reply-btn-1').after(secondButton);
}

$('#reply-btn-1').click(function(e){    
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'submit':1, 'post':2}        
  })
  //to be replaced with .done(function(response){
  .always(function(response){    
    //create the second button only if it didn't exist yet
    if( $('#reply-btn-2').length < 1 )
      createAndAppendSecondButton();
    const text1 = 'Reply 1<br>';      
    $('.place-replies-here').append(text1);                      
  });
});
```

```css
.place-replies-here{
  border: solid 3px gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#reply-btn-1{
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  margin:8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#reply-btn-2{
  height:40px;
  width:100px;
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
  padding:5px;
  margin:8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#reply-btn-2:disabled{
  background: gray !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="place-replies-here"></div>

<button id="reply-btn-1" class="reply-btn">Reply 1</button>
```

Comment: Actually, I want the `post_reply` function to be called only when the `ajax' has been successful. So it is necessary that it is wrapped inside the `ajax` function

Comment: it's not perfectly clear to me. Your post_reply function was just adding an event listener. So I don't understand what do you mean by saying that such a function was needed to run only when the ajax request from the first button was fulfilled. Did you mean that the second button shouldn't react to events if the first one wasn't pressed yet?

Comment: Yes, the second button should react to events if the first one wasn't pressed yet. Sufficiently, the post_reply function should run only after the first button has been clicked and only the second button is pressed.

Comment: it's hard to understand your thoughts. feel free to try the latest interpretation I made of your words in my answer. if it still doesn't address your expectation I guess it was my last attempt.

Comment: My original code works like this
(1) Call first ajax 
(2) When first ajax is successful, create new HTML button called reply button 2
(3) When the reply button 2 is pressed, react according to the click.
Hopefully this is a better explanation

Comment: yes it's a much better explanation but I want to be sure... the latest solution I implemented shows both the buttons since the beginning, but the second one is disabled. It becomes active again as soon as the first button is pressed (and the ajax request returned successfully). Since the second button is now active, it can be clicked to trigger its corresponding action (writing Reply2 on target). Your latest explanation behaves exactly like that but it just makes the second button appear instead of enabling it. isn't it?

Comment: Yest, that would solve the problem I presented.  The issue is when an HMTL element is created through ajax, jQuery does not interact with the element except when the jQuery is called within the ajax as well. That is why my post_reply function is called inside the ajax.

Comment: I edited one more time my question with the second button created from scratch when the first button gets pressed

Comment: Yes your code works. But it looks similar to mine. Can you give me some explanation why yours works? Your createAndAppendSecondButton() function is called inside the ajax of the first button like my post_reply() function. Why does yours not fire multiple times?

Comment: I tried to tell you in many ways before that your function was just selecting the element already existing in the dom and adding the click event listener. My function instead creates the html element dynamically, adds the click event listener to it and appends it to the DOM right next to the other button. It runs  only once when the first button gets clicked and it will never run anymore on subsequent clicks. It checks if the element already exists before doing it’s job. There are comments in my code marking stages on that function

Comment: Anyway I suggest you to better study what’s an event listener because you showed to be very confused about it

Comment: by the way this was the check to see if the element existed before attempting to create it again and appending it to the dom: `if( $('#reply-btn-2').length < 1 )`. The code can't be more clear than that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your second button event handler is nested within the function called from the first button. Therefore every time you click button one, button 2 gets a duplicated event handler.

To fix this, and DRY the code up, put a common class on both buttons and use that to select them. From there you can use `data` attributes to store the custom metadata you use in the AJAX request. Using this method means that a single event handler will work for both buttons - and any ones you add in the future - without having to change any lines of JS code.

Also note that you shouldn't put inline CSS in your HTML. You an external stylesheet for that.

Here's working example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="place-replies-here"></div>
<div class="reply-btn" data-submit="1" data-post="2">Reply 1</div>
<div class="btn btn-success reply-btn" data-submit="3" data-post="4">Reply 2</div>
```

```js
$('.reply-btn').on('click', e => {
  let $btn = $(e.target);
  let text = $btn.text();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      submit: $btn.data('submit'),
      post: $btn.data('post')
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    $('.place-replies-here').append(text);
  });
});
```

```css
.reply-btn {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I want the function `post_reply` to be called only when the first ajax function has been successful and only when the second button has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple check to see if the code is able to run or not. This way you are not binding events. Could be a boolean or a variable that has the current step.

```js
let currentStep = 1;

$('#reply-btn-1').click(function(e) {

  var text1 = 'Reply 1<br>';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'submit': 1,
      'post': 2
    }

  }).done(function(response) {
    currentStep = 2;
    $('.place-replies-here').append(text1);
  });
});

$('#reply-btn-2').click(function(e) {

  if (currentStep != 2) return;

  var text2 = 'Reply 2<br>';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'submit': 1,
      'post': 2
    }
  }).done(function(response) {
    $('.place-replies-here').append(text2);
  });
});
```